# How to create a function to avoid repetitive steps?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

I want to create a function to avoid the code repetition on Cypress.

**Task:**

I need to log in with different types of users (with different permissions) and want to check which type of user gets a "403 Forbidden" error on the desired path. Since I have 6 types of users and 11 different paths the code below repeats itself for every single user/path, which I'm not happy with that.

```
        cy.visit('/abc')

          .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
          .should('exist')
          .contains('403')
          .visit('/def')
          .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
          .should('exist')
          .contains('403')

          .get('[data-qa="logout"]')
          .click()
```

How can I create a function, something like check403(), and implement the set of controls inside it? So that the code will look like this:

```
          cy.visit('/abc')
            .check403()
            .visit('/def')
            .check403()
            .get('[data-qa="logout"]')
            .click()
```

If I can create something like this, I will be able to remove a huge amount of repetitive code.

**What I tried:**

- I tried to create a Cypress Custom Command but it didn't work.
- I tried to create a function and moved it outside the actual case and called it like `cy.check403()` but then I got `cy.check403() is not a function` error on Cypress.

**Update**

I've defined all the users inside `users.json` under fixtures folder.
I'm logging in with every single user separately and do the rest.
My code is placed under `afterlogin.spec.js`.

Here is the full code but it's too long to achieve such a basic task. Maybe it helps:

```
it('Unauthorized users are redirected to a 403 page', () => {
cy.fixture('users.json').then(users => {
  cy.login(
    users[Cypress.env('ENVIRONMENT')].driver,
    Cypress.env('DEFAULT_USER_PASSWORD')
  ).then(response => {
    cy.setCookie('__bl_pp__', response.body.result.access_token)
      .visit('/me')
      .get('[data-qa="roles"]')
      .contains('driver')
      .visit('/offers')
      .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
      .should('exist')
      .contains('403')
      .get('[data-qa="back-to-homepage"]')
      .should('exist')
      .visit('/drivers')
      .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
      .should('exist')
      .contains('403')
      .get('[data-qa="logout"]')
      .click()

    cy.login(
      users[Cypress.env('ENVIRONMENT')].dispatcher,
      Cypress.env('DEFAULT_USER_PASSWORD')
    ).then(response => {
      cy.setCookie('__bl_pp__', response.body.result.access_token)
        .visit('/me')
        .get('[data-qa="roles"]')
        .contains('dispatcher')
        .visit('/offers')
        .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
        .should('exist')
        .contains('403')
        .get('[data-qa="logout"]')
        .click()

      cy.login(
        users[Cypress.env('ENVIRONMENT')].provider,
        Cypress.env('DEFAULT_USER_PASSWORD')
      ).then(response => {
        cy.setCookie('__bl_pp__', response.body.result.access_token)
          .visit('/me')
          .get('[data-qa="roles"]')
          .contains('provider')
          .visit('/planned')
          .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
          .should('exist')
          .contains('403')
          .visit('/finished')
          .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
          .should('exist')
          .contains('403')
          .get('[data-qa="logout"]')
          .click()

        cy.login(
          users[Cypress.env('ENVIRONMENT')].reviewer,
          Cypress.env('DEFAULT_USER_PASSWORD')
        ).then(response => {
          cy.setCookie('__bl_pp__', response.body.result.access_token)
            .visit('/me')
            .get('[data-qa="roles"]')
            .contains('reviewer')
            .visit('/offers')
            .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
            .should('exist')
            .contains('403')
            .visit('/planned')
            .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
            .should('exist')
            .contains('403')
            .get('[data-qa="logout"]')
            .click()

          cy.login(
            users[Cypress.env('ENVIRONMENT')].admin,
            Cypress.env('DEFAULT_USER_PASSWORD')
          ).then(response => {
            cy.setCookie('__bl_pp__', response.body.result.access_token)
              .visit('/me')
              .get('[data-qa="roles"]')
              .contains('admin')
              .visit('/offers')
              .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
              .should('exist')
              .contains('403')
              .visit('/planned')
              .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
              .should('exist')
              .contains('403')
              .visit('/finished')
              .get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
              .should('exist')
              .contains('403')
              .get('[data-qa="logout"]')
              .click()
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you post the error you got when the custom command didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom command.  You said you tried one and it didn't work, but I am doing something similar successfully in my tests.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("check403", () => {
  cy.get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
    .should('exist')
    .should('contain', '403'); // I changed this - you didn't mention that it
      // didn't work, but it would have been returning an element, not asserting
});
```

Comment: I'll re-run my code and let you know about the error message. I guess I didn't return an element. That was the mistake probably.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure where users and paths are fitting in the code shown, but you can repeat a test with a plain javascript loop, for example

```js
const users = ['Joe', 'Jim', 'John']
const paths = ['Add', 'Edit', 'Remove']

users.forEach(user => {
  paths.forEach(path => {

    it(`should test user '${user}' and path '${path}'`, => {
      // test code here
    })

  })
})
```

---

Maybe this,

```
const roles = ['driver', 'dispatcher', 'provider', 'reviewer', 'admin'];

context('Unauthorized users are redirected to a 403 page', () => {
  cy.fixture('users.json').then(users => {

    const user = users[Cypress.env('ENVIRONMENT')];
    roles.forEach(role => {

      it(`testing user '${user}' and role '${role}'`, () => {

        cy.login(user[role], Cypress.env('DEFAULT_USER_PASSWORD'))
          .then(response => {
            cy.setCookie('__bl_pp__', response.body.result.access_token);
            cy.visit('/me').get('[data-qa="roles"]').contains(role);
            cy.visit('/offers').get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
              .should('exist').contains('403')
              .get('[data-qa="back-to-homepage"]').should('exist')
            cy.visit('/drivers').get('[data-qa="http-error.section"]')
              .should('exist').contains('403')
              .get('[data-qa="logout"]').click()
          })
      })
  })
```

Comment: I've updated and added the full code. I'd love to implement something like this but since I need to log in with them separately I can't imagine the correct way to implement the one that you wrote.